# module.exports is not returning functions in nodejs

Tags: node.js, function

Everyone I'm beginner in NODE.JS i'm using module.exports function inside that I have written hello function in it.I tried to import from other file.but it's not working.Can anyone solve this problem.Thanks in advance...

```html
index.js


module.exports=function(){   
         
    hello:(data)=>{
       return "Good night" +data;
    }
}



trail.js



const index=require('./index');
const e=new index();
console.log(e.hello("abc"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using a function as a constructor, [creating `new` objects from it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), you'll have to reference each of those objects with `this` to assign their properties:

```
module.exports=function(){
    this.hello = (data) => {
        return "Good night" +data;
    };
}
```

The syntax `<identifier>:` has different meanings depending on its placement/surroundings. When used within a function body, at the start of a statement, it only defines a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). To have it define a property, it would have to be used within an [object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution slightly we have to change the code in index.js.In ES6 Functional constructors are available.we should use this keyword this keywords refers current class objects.because In javascript Functions are first class Objects.correct me If I'm wrong. post the answer if anyone knows Others solution are also always welcome....

```html
Index.js


module.exports=function(){   

   this.hello=(data)=>{
       return "Good night" +data;
    }
}

Trail.js

const index=require('./index');
const e=new index();
console.log(e.hello("abc"));
```

Comment: You can just return a function from the `Index.js`, e.g. `module.exports = (data) => 'Good night ' + data;`. Then just require it and call directly 
`const hello =require('./index');`

`console.log(hello('abc'))`

Answer (score 0):

you can also use it this way:

```
module.exports=function(data){   
    return "Good night" +data;
}

const temp = require('./index');
console.log(temp('demo developer'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is the correct desicion you tring to find out, but may be you would like to go this way:

index.js:

```
exports.hello = data => {
  return 'Good night ' + data;
};
```

trail.js:

```
const e = require('./index');
console.log(e.hello('Jhonny'));
```